# Redirect lync internal user calls to elastix and record it

Tags: lync, elastix

We want to redirect all Lync voice chats ( Calls ) to an Elastix server.

We also want to disable lync built in Voice chats ( all voice communication - "included internal lync users" - through Elastix )

Our goal is "record" voice chats on a Central and server based solution Like elastix.

Is it possible ?

How we can do this ?

Comment: Do you want to disable, or redirect+record Lync calls?  These two goals are mutually-exclusive.

Comment: @gWaldo  our main goal is record internal lync users on Elastix .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Lync/Skype4Business alone.

You can change the default behavior - so PSTN/VOIP is the default vs. P2P

```
Set-CsclientPolicy EnableVoipCallDefault $true
```

This however does not remove the ability to make a P2P call and the client can override this setting.  I'm not aware of a method to disable P2P calling option.

If you need to capture internal calls thru Lync you will most likely need a third party product that is installed on the servers like [SmartTap](http://www.audiocodes.com/products/smarttap-call-recording-solution)